# Require e include

Tags: php, include, require

Ola estou com uma dúvida no seguinte:

Classe: "Teste1.php"

```
<?php
class Teste1{}...
?>
```

- Ex1- include 'Teste1.php'
- Ex2- include_once 'teste1.php'
- Ex3- require_once 'Teste1.php'

É possível chamar teste1(em minusculo), como no Ex2? Irá funcionar?

Vi em alguns blogs que é só no php 4, a partir dai não está correto por ser case sensitive, esta certo isso?

Obrigada

Answer (score 2):

Em sistemas de arquivos *case-insensitive*, como é o caso do Windows, não faz diferença. Porém, o Linux é *case-sensitive*!

Por experiência própria, eu utilizava os arquivos com os nomes minúsculos e o *AutoLoader com PSR-4* carregava meus arquivos normalmente utilizando até mesmo o PHP 7.2 (Atual). Porém, ao rodar meu projeto no Linux, também com *PHP 7.2*, tive que renomear meus arquivos atento ao *case-sensitive*.

O ideal é incluir os arquivos sempre atento à letras maiúsculas e minúsculas, já que é possível que troque de ambiente com o passar do tempo.

Answer (score 1):

Funciona assim:

```
<?php
include_once "a.php"; // vai carregar o ficheiro a.php
include_once "A.php"; // vai carregar o ficheiro a.php novamente! (só no PHP4)
?>
```

Este comportamento alterou no PHP5. Ou seja, o ficheiro é carregado apenas uma vez.

**fonte:** http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php